# How to check if a style does not exist in Microsoft Word?

Tags: vb.net, vsto, cpu-word

I can not get a negative answer if the style is not in the style list

#### Example:

```
If Styles("FirstLine").BuiltIn = False Then

    Application.ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:="FirstLine", Type:=wdStyleTypeParagraph)
    Application.ActiveDocument.Styles("FirstLine").AutomaticallyUpdate = False

    With Application.ActiveDocument.Styles("FirstLine").Frame
        .TextWrap = True
        .HorizontalPosition = wdFrameRight 
        .HorizontalDistanceFromText = 4
        .LockAnchor = False
    End With
End If
```

And he returns the answer:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The requested member of
> the collection does not exist.'

How can I get a negative answer?

Comment: Should `Styles` be `ThisWorkbook.Styles`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - which line of code is causing the error? What are you trying to do?

Comment: A dispatch sent to an error is "If". I'm trying to create a new style in Ward only if the style does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solutions in both VB.NET & VBA to check if a style exists in Word before adding it.

#### VB.NET

```
Public Sub AddNewStyle(ByVal styleName As String)
    Try
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Purpose:  Create a new style in Microsoft Word
        ' Example:  AddNewStyle("YourNewStyleNameHere")
        '           AddNewStyle("Medium Grid 3 - Accent 4") 'a default style from Microsoft Word 2016
        '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim MyDocument As Word.Document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
        Dim styleExist As Boolean = False

        Dim style As Word.Style
        For Each style In Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Styles
            If styleName = style.NameLocal Then
                styleExist = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next style

        If Not styleExist Then
            Dim MyStyle As Word.Style = MyDocument.Styles.Add(styleName, Word.WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph)
            MyDocument.Styles(styleName).AutomaticallyUpdate = False

            With MyDocument.Styles(styleName).Frame
                .TextWrap = True
                .HorizontalPosition = Word.WdFramePosition.wdFrameRight
                .HorizontalDistanceFromText = 4
                .LockAnchor = False
            End With

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Contact your system administrator." + Environment.NewLine + "Description: " + ex.ToString(), vbOK + vbExclamation, "Unexpected Error")

    End Try

End Sub
```

#### VBA

```
Public Sub AddNewStyle(ByVal styleName As String)
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Create a new style in Microsoft Word
' Example:  AddNewStyle "YourNewStyleNameHere"
'           AddNewStyle "Medium Grid 3 - Accent 4" 'a default style from Microsoft Word 2016
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim MyStyle As Word.Style
Dim msg As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set MyStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles(styleName)

    On Error GoTo ErrTrap
    If Not MyStyle Is Nothing Then
        Set MyStyle = Application.ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(styleName, wdStyleTypeParagraph)
        Application.ActiveDocument.Styles(styleName).AutomaticallyUpdate = False

        With Application.ActiveDocument.Styles(styleName).Frame
            .TextWrap = True
            .HorizontalPosition = wdFrameRight
            .HorizontalDistanceFromText = 4
            .LockAnchor = False
        End With

    End If

ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set MyStyle = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Is <> 0
            msg = "Contact your system administrator."
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & "Procedure: AddNewStyle"
            msg = msg & IIf(Line = 0, "", vbCrLf & "Error Line: " & Erl)
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & "Error #: " & Err.Number
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description
            MsgBox msg, vbCritical, "Unexpected Error"
            Resume ExitProcedure
        Case Else
            Resume ExitProcedure
    End Select

End Sub
```